# Why does setImageBitmap override layout_height and layout_width?

Tags: android, xml

For the following layout:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myid"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
/>
```

If i have a 400x400dp bitmap, why does calling `setImageBitmap` with it override the width and height? In other words: why does does an imageview with width and height set to 200 show up as 400x400 instead of automatically scaling the image?

I know that there is an option to manually rescale the bitmap, but it seems odd that if I already specified the dimensions of my imageview in the layout, I still have to rescale the image.

Comment: What evidence do you have that it overrides the width and height? I just tried it, and it does not override the width and height. They remained `200dp` apiece. The image simply will not fill the `ImageView`, and the remaining `ImageView` background is transparent by default.

Answer (score 2):

use [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) FIT_XY or CENTER_CROP if you want to mantain the ratio

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

> `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Scale in X and Y independently, so that src matches dst exactly. This may change the aspect ratio of the src.

Comment: I tried all the different scaleTypes. Calling setImageBitmap seems to ignore it, and make the width of the imageview larger than what I defined in the xml

Comment: It's just: bmImage.setImageBitmap(result); 
where bmImage is my imageview, and result is a bitmap

Comment: not just that line, all the code please. Also tell me if you set the image at the xml with the property android:src, does it work as expected?